# How do I make the date input field the scrolling type rather than having to type in the date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out the right words to use to find this for myself. So instead of having to type something like 06 24 2015 or something I could select it from a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something as [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

if you are already use jQuery then it will be only 1 line:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

assuming your input field has class datepicker

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Rails-only-solution, the [date_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) function from the `DateHelper`-Module is exactly doing that.

But I agree with @mohamed-ibrahim, that the use of JavaScript would be appropriate in this case.